# Remove Archive: from Events Page title

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have been stuck with this problem for quite a while now and I am not sure what to do anymore. I tried to google the problem but nothing of the solutions (CSS and PHP) helped.

Anyone can help me in removing only the “Archive:” portion from the page title?

I am using The Events Calendar plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested using the Yoast SEO plugin to remove this?

Comment: No. I dont know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually depends on the theme you are using. Try to search the title function from your Archive.php page.

Quick fix! Add this to your CSS.

```
body.post-type-archive-tribe_events .page-title .col-md-12.page-title-container h1 { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Can you help me to remove this or hide from these pages. I made some sample event and checked event detail page. But it views on this page too.

Comment: Sure kindly share your website link and your theme name

Comment: Quick fix! Add this to your CSS.

Comment: body.post-type-archive-tribe_events .page-title .col-md-12.page-title-container h1 {
 display: none !important;
}

Comment: Hi @Shaharyar, Please check this link too. How can i remove these ?
http://acboa.lk/events/annual-general-meeting-2018/

Comment: What you want to remove from that link?

Comment: I want to remove archive part on all pages 
http://acboa.lk/hire-a-branding-consultant-with-a-similar-aesthetic-to-your-own-2/

Comment: That "Archive" part on your left sidebar is added through Appearance => Widgets. Kindly remove it from there

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Yoast SEO plugin. Ref: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

The Events Calendar docs provide you with the [full instruction](https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/titles-in-yoast-seo/) on how to do what you ask.

Install a WordPress child theme, within the *child theme* **functions.php** file paste this:

```
    // Prevent Yoast from changing Event Title Tags for Event Views (Month, List, Etc,)
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tribe_remove_wpseo_title_rewrite', 20 );
    function tribe_remove_wpseo_title_rewrite() {
        if ( class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Main' ) && class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Pro__Main' ) ) {
            if( tribe_is_month() || tribe_is_upcoming() || tribe_is_past() || tribe_is_day() || tribe_is_map() || tribe_is_photo() || tribe_is_week() ) {
                $wpseo_front = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
                remove_filter( 'wp_title', array( $wpseo_front, 'title' ), 15 );
                remove_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', array( $wpseo_front, 'title' ), 15 );
            }
        } elseif ( class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Main' ) && !class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Pro__Main' ) ) {
            if( tribe_is_month() || tribe_is_upcoming() || tribe_is_past() || tribe_is_day() ) {
                $wpseo_front = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
                remove_filter( 'wp_title', array( $wpseo_front, 'title' ), 15 );
                remove_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', array( $wpseo_front, 'title' ), 15 );
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: umm i think its not the plugin issue.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my post. Yoast SEO will allow you to easily change the archive title that you refer to. Either that or you refer to something other then the <title> meta tag for the page.